# Lock/unlock mutex under timer interrupt

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it safe to lock a mutex in a timer handler (kernel space)? 
I have two kernel modules which read /write to the same I2C device: 
- first module: launch a timer when loaded. Read I2C register under timer handler every 20 ms
- second module: read/write the same I2C register

I have seen many kernel crash (CPU 1 is freezed) 
--> I suspect that when trying to unlock mutex under timer handler, kernel freezes Could you comfirm that ?

Comment: You can't use sleeping primitives in atomic or irq context. Use spin_lock instead.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupt handlers shouldn't use mutexes for locking. That is because if any code outside the ISR tries to hold the mutex, but before completing that operation, the ISR executes and then tries to hold the ISR, it may crash because **the mutex will be in an undeterminate form**.

**Why can't I use a mutex, if I lock only from ISR and not from outside?**

Mutexes are designed for threaded applications were a thread can be blocked until the other is in the critical section. Since your ISR isn't blockable, i.e. you can't pause it because the ISR itself will have to return in time by `IRET`.

**What locking mechanism should I use in an ISR?**

Spinlocks are generally safer in the ISR. But while locking and unlocking, you have to be sure to use **atomic primitiives** so that an ISR can't come in between and try acquire the lock when it was being locked by something else.

You could use a simple RW lock also where the readers can enter  simultaneously. When a writer enters, it will wait for all the readers to exit, and will block any incoming readers by not letting go of the lock.